# How to manage external application form size and position?

Tags: delphi

From a central main gui application written in DelphiXE2 I want to manage (size, position )  many host external application form ( delphi6 ,delphiXE2 ) in a MDIChild/Tabbed style.
My idea is to manage "virtual" panel ( or form ) inside the main gui application hosting the external form ,with "hosting " I mean anchor size and position of virtual form to external one.

Some idea to achieve that ?

Comment: Find the window handle of the main form of each external application and call `SetParent` to re-parent it. Then I wish you all the best in making it actually work. Not at all easy to do.

Comment: @David Thanks , it seems a good start.I don't know was possibile to parent an external window handle. Here I found some other tips (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/796883/how-to-shell-to-another-app-and-have-it-appear-in-a-delphi-form)

Comment: Whilst it is possible, it's exceptionally hard to do

Comment: @David Why it is so hard :( ? Can you give me some advice on problems I could have ? My idea now is to reparent directly in external form creation.

Comment: It's hard because you have multiple processes.